# Radius of convergence/ analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let
$$f_1(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n} $$

$$f_2(z) = i\pi + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^n}\frac{(z-2)^n}{n} $$

I need to calculate the radii of convergence and see that they do not overlap, and show that there exists a holomorphic function which is the analytic continuation of $f_1$ and $f_2$.

For $f_1$ I have calculated $R=1$ via the ratio test (Is it correct?), however for the second I do not how to proceed, the constant term $i\pi$ is confusing me. And I also do not know how to do the analytic continuation

Edit: for the second I also get $R=1$, and the interval of convergence for the $f_1$ would be (-1,1) and for the $f_2$ would be (1,3)? Would that be correct? which theorem can give me the analytic continuation?

Comment: @Sam That's not correct. The $i\pi$ shifts the range of the function, not the domain which is unchanged. Any finite number of terms can be ignored or altered without changing the region of convergence of a series.

Comment: @GregMartin true! what a blunder from my side. Deleted.

Comment: Note for the radius of convergence of $f_2$: like Greg Martin said, you do not have to worry about the $i\pi$, as what matters for the ratio test, as well as the Cauchy-Hadamard formula and so on... is the behaviour of the sequence of the coefficients when $n$ goes to $\infty$, so any modification on a finite number of terms is indeed fine. Also yes $R = 1$ is true for $f_1$.

Comment: @BrunoB, thank you, I tried to calculate the second R, would be great if you could check it.

Comment: Yeah, $R = 1$. However, since we're in $\mathbb{C}$, the domains of convergence are gonna be disks (discs?) in the complex plane and not intervals of $\mathbb{R}$.